# How to hide blob url and SAS token in the azcopy in the command prompt

Tags: amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage, command-prompt, azcopy

Am trying to copy the files from **AWS S3 to Azure blob**. To do that i have used **azcopy**.

I have downloaded azcopy in my windows machine and accessed it via command prompt.

As needed, i have set my AWS secret key and access key ID in the **azcopy env**

Now, i can move the files from S3 to blob

But to do that each time am giving the SAS token in the command. Is it possible to hide it or is it possible to pass via a file

```
cp "https://s3.amazonaws.com/testblobutopud/"   "SAS token" --recursive
```

I do not need to pass this token directly in command...cAn someone help me in this

Error:
[image]
[image]

Environment variable
[image]

[image]

Comment: what's your real purpose? do you provide this command to others and want to prevent sasToken reveal? or something else?

Comment: yeah, exactly we don't want reveal the SAS token to others @IvanYang

Comment: @IvanYang  Could u pls help me in this?

Comment: Yes, please see the answer below, and let me know if you have any concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:**

please set your sastoken in Environment Variable, like it's name is `bloburl_sastoken`, and use double quotes to wrap it's value(it's value looks like this: `https://blobtestutopus.blob.core.windows.net/?sv=2019-10-10&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupx&se=2020-07-17T10:09:48Z&st=2020-07-17T02:09:48Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxxxxxx`).

Then in the command prompt, use the code below:

```
set temp_chars=""

set temp_url=%temp_chars%%bloburl_sastoken%

set url_sastoken=%temp_url:""=%

azcopy cp "https://s3.amazonaws.com/testblobutopud/" %url_sastoken%
```

---

**Original answer:**

You can store the sasToken in the Environment variable. The steps are as below:

**Step 1:** Set an Environment Variable, you can use command or UI to do this. Here, I just set it via UI. Note that for it's value, you should wrap the value in **double quotes** in English mode. The screenshot as below:

[image]

**Step 2:** then open a cmd prompt, and use the code below(please **remove the comments section**):

```
//set a variable for the blob url
set url="https://yy1.blob.core.windows.net/test5/myfoo1.txt"

//set a variable which contains blob url and sastoken
set temp_url=%url%%mysastoken%

//remove the redundant double quotes in blob url and sastoken
set url_sastoken=%temp_url:""=%

//copy it
azcopy copy "d:\foo.txt" %url_sastoken%
```

Another way is that you can use [AzCopy login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-s3#authorize-with-azure-storage) command, then you don't need to use sastoken here.

Comment: MAny thanks, for your reply. But i have one question. I am transferring files from AWS S3 to Azure blob. In that case i no need to do this right `set url="https://yy1.blob.core.windows.net/test5/myfoo1.txt"`

Comment: @Kanagambala, I don't have the aws environment. If you don't need it, just remove it:)

Comment: I have a question...If i user Azcopy login...if my SAS token expires...how will that work?

Comment: @Kanagambala, are you referring to this [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-s3)? In this doc, I see we always need to specify a blob url.

Comment: @Kanagambala, if you follow this official doc, and then use `Azcopy login`, then you don't need to use sastoken for authentication so that there is nothing about sastoken expires.

Comment: yes, pls bare with me, i am new to azure.  If am not using SAS token, how it will know in which blob files should be transferred

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218004/discussion-between-ivan-yang-and-kanagam-bala).

Comment: I have attached the output..pls help me